# Add multiple UV maps via Python

Tags: python, scripting

I have many objects in scene, script should add new UVMap to each object, make it "smart project" and select previous UVMap (so, 2 UVMaps for each object). But it add a few UVMaps to one object - as much UVMaps as objects in scene. How to fix it? Thank you.

```
import bpy


for ob in bpy.context.visible_objects:
    ob.select = True
    bpy.ops.mesh.uv_texture_add()
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    bpy.ops.uv.smart_project()
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    bpy.context.object.data.uv_textures['UVMap'].active = True
    ob.select = False
```

Comment: General tip: its good to make your title somewhat more related to your actual issue.

Comment: I don't know how to edit topic on this website, sorry. But I will try make my titles more related to issue in future. Thank you.

Comment: Stackexchange is a colaborative editing effort to create a q&a-database. [Click here](https://i.imgur.com/cCiR0QD.png) to edit, this will also have the positive side effect, that the improved post will be bumped to the top of the *hot question* list.

Comment: You need to set the object active, not selected. In 2.8 this is bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj in 2.79 that is bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj.

Comment: Thank you so much! It really resolved my problem!